# Is there any option to add user-agent in streaming media Exo Player?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-videoview

I'm facing a problem with exomedia player, I want to add support for some types of streaming url s but exomedia won't accept them,I have tried to much time to add the option " User AGENT" but can't turn it on, I have added my code  and if there is someone who can help to fix this ?

I have tried  to add User -Agent ,but in this code The player runs smooth but not some type of urls

```
public class ActivityStreaming extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {

private long exitTime = 0;
private VideoView videoView;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_streaming);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    videoView.start();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void closeStreaming() {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.press_again_to_close_streaming), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "add user-agent"? Are you trying to get exoPlayer to report as a specific user-agent when requesting the streams? What happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @colde Im trying to play this type of streaming file, and tried to many times to find any way but not the application is based on client server and  I add channels from my online panel, this is the type of file ---                       '   
        
    http://163.172.212.71:8000/live/topchannel/a5TZGucS8p/41.ts|user-agent=asdfghgfdfghjhgfd

Comment: That looks like you are trying to play a HLS stream. You probably want to play the URL ending in .m3u8 instead of the individual .ts files.

Comment: there are .ts files with useragent..

Comment: Yes but how to make it possible???

Comment: @fatlindpalushi did you managed to make it work?